# Problema ao fazer método que verifica qual botão foi clicado

Tags: android

Estou criando uma tela com 3 botoes no qual cada botao ao clicado precisará ser redirecinado a um site diferente. Implementei esse codigo, nao da nenhum erro, eu ate consigo clicar no botao, so que quando a pagina é carregada ha um erro na aplicaçao e ele fecha sozinho. O que estou fazendo de errado nesse metodo?
[image: erro]

Comment: Que erro dá? Poste o *log* de erros.

Comment: Se ao clicar no botão a página abre então o erro não é no botão.

Comment: Outro erro que percebi, é que mesmo sem apertar o botao ele entrar no links, um atras do outro. É como se essas condiçoes nao tivessem valendo

Comment: kkkk Agora que parei pra olhar não nenhuma função de clique aí

Comment: Tudo isso aí é executado quando o OnCreateView() é iniciado.

Comment: Já te mostro como se faz uma função dessa.

Comment: Blz Bruno, estou no aguardo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Esse código que você postou não tem uma função de clique, ele está executando tudo isso quando o `OnCreateView()` é iniciado. Tente fazer assim:

Na sua classe, logo após o `extends Cronograma`, adicione `implements View.OnClickListener`.

E no `OnCreateView()` faça isso:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.solicitacoes, container, false);
    Button button1 = view.findViewById(R.id.id_do_button1);
    Button button2 = view.findViewById(R.id.id_do_button2);
    Button button3 = view.findViewById(R.id.id_do_button3);
    button1.setOnClickListener(this);
    button2.setOnClickListener(this);
    button3.setOnClickListener(this);

  return view;
 }
```

Então para finalizar é só criar(o termo correto acho que é implementar) a função do `OnClick`:  
**Obs:** Dei uma simplificada na sua função usando `switch` ao invés do `if`, levando em conta que você só quer pegar o evento de clique dos botões nessa `classe`:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
   String url = "";
   switch (v.getId()) {
     case R.id.button:
       url = "sua url aqui";
       break;
     case R.id.button:
       url = "sua url aqui";
       break;
     default: // padrão, seria igual o else aqui
       url = "url padrão aqui";
       break;

     Intent it = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url))...
     startActivity(it);
   }
}
```

Comment: Bruno so mais uma duvida, nessa linha: View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.solicitacoes, container, false);
    Button seuButton = view.findViewById(R.id.id_do_seu_button);
    seuButton.setOnClickListener(this) eu coloco o id de cada botaow(no meu caso 3 botoes)?

Comment: Perfetio Bruno, mto obgdo. a aplicaçao ta rodando lisinha.